# Delete duplicate records based on timestamps

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table tblCost which contains:

```
RecordID    ProjectID    Cost    AllocationMonthYear    TimeStamp    
112            1         $1000       10/17              10/16/2017 12:09:53 PM 
113            1         $1200       11/17              10/16/2017 01:14:45 PM 
114            1         $1000       10/17              10/16/2017 02:21:23 PM
```

AllocationMonthYear is the month for which the budget is allocated. My problem is that the software is located on a shared drive and used by multiple users. They often add duplicate record for the same month. I need a query to delete the duplicate record based on the latest timestamp, i.e, record 114 ought to be deleted because it is a duplicate of 112 and is LATER than 112.
Any pointers highly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM tblCost AS C1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tblCost AS C2
              WHERE C1.AllocationMonthYear = C2.AllocationMonthYear    
                AND C1.ProjectID   = C2.ProjectID    
                AND C1.TimeStamp   > C2.TimeStamp)
```

Also you could add one unique index to avoid this continue happening

[Unique constraint on multiple fields in Access 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635811/unique-constraint-on-multiple-fields-in-access-2003)

Comment: OP: this is called a "self join."

Comment: Wow that worked. Thanks Juan. I wasted a day trying to move it into a temporary table, creating a join between the temp table , original table, deleting from temp table and then replacing again in the original table.