# MS Access: How to prevent from booking one room in few times for one date

Tags: ms-access

I have simple database.
It contains 2 tables.

1. Rooms
2. Reservations

They is relations via room ID.
How can I prevent in Reservation table to do not make a reservation for one room in the same date?

Answer (score 0):

you can insert an unique constraint on fields (roomID and reservationDate).
In this way you'll can have only a reservation for a room in a date.
If you want to unlock a room, you'll have to delete a reservation row.

Comment: Ok, but how to set it?

Comment: you can retrieve the information for add a new constraint in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635811/unique-constraint-on-multiple-fields-in-access-2003